# Select ids that start with the same letter in a python dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary with names and ages:

```
classmates = {'Anne':15, 'Laura':17, 'Michel':16, 'Lee':15, 'Mick':17, 'Liz':16}
```

I want to select all the names that with the letter "L". I can do it like this:

```
for name, age in classmates.items():
    if "L" in name:
        print(name)
```

or

```
Lnames = [name for name in classmates.items() if "L" in name]
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing when I have millions of entries and I need to repeat the operation millions of times?

Comment: look at [`str.startswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith)

Comment: Don't use `"L" in name`, which searches the entire name for `"L"`.  Instead, use `name.startswith("L")` which will just look at the start of the name.

Comment: true, I can use `name.startswith("L")`, but how much faster is this method?

Comment: @aLbAc Depends on how much data you have. In terms of algorithmic complexity, in your case `startswith` is constant time, whereas `in` is linear time. Also, `startswith` is the more correct approach since you only care if something starts with the letter.

Answer (score 1):

One liner with `List Comprehension`.

```
[ key for key in classmates.keys() if key.startswith('L') ]
```

## #driver values

```
In : classmates = {'Anne':15, 'Laura':17, 'Michel':16, 'Lee':15, 'Mick':17, 'Liz':16}
Out : ['Lee', 'Liz', 'Laura']
```

As others have pointed out, use `startswith` instead of `in` to find if a character is there at the start.

Comment: I don't get what `... or key.startswith('I')` is useful in this case if I only want the ones that starts with "L"...

Comment: @aLbAc , your previous edit made it look like you required both words starting with `L` and `I` . Have changed it since your last edit.

Comment: Kaushik NP right, I see what you mean, I modified that.

Comment: How does `key.startswith('L')` compare with `key[0] == 'L'` in terms of performance?

Comment: Also, try `[ key for key in classmates.keys() ...` - we're not interested in the values, so don't handle them.

Comment: Had Forgot that @attie. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There will be no performance in your search time until you use some kind of parallel computations. You can use the filtering that @Kaushnik NP mentioned on filtering splitted chunks of data on several processes.
So you have to split your dictionary in 4 smaller dictionaries (dependent on number of cores your processor has), run a worker on each of chunks and store your common data somewhere.
Here is a snippet that uses multiprocessing python lib and queues to schedule some work and store the results of that work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import multiprocessing, os, signal, time, Queue

def do_work():
    print 'Work Started: %d' % os.getpid()
    time.sleep(2)
    return 'Success'

def manual_function(job_queue, result_queue):
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)
    while not job_queue.empty():
        try:
            job = job_queue.get(block=False)
            result_queue.put(do_work())
        except Queue.Empty:
            pass
        #except KeyboardInterrupt: pass

def main():
    job_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    result_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

    for i in range(6):
        job_queue.put(None)

    workers = []
    for i in range(3):
        tmp = multiprocessing.Process(target=manual_function,
                                      args=(job_queue, result_queue))
        tmp.start()
        workers.append(tmp)

    try:
        for worker in workers:
            worker.join()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print 'parent received ctrl-c'
        for worker in workers:
            worker.terminate()
            worker.join()

    while not result_queue.empty():
        print result_queue.get(block=False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

For other examples on that topic, [use that link](http://bryceboe.com/2010/08/26/python-multiprocessing-and-keyboardinterrupt/)